# Radio buttons do not uncheck in Sharepoint when a different button is clicked

Tags: html, forms, sharepoint, radio-button

I have this list of radio-buttons in Sharepoint:

```
<input type="radio" name="fruit" value="apple"/> Apple<br/>
<input type="radio" name="fruit" value="pear"/> Pear<br/>
<input type="radio" name="fruit" value="orange"/> Orange<br/>
<input type="radio" name="fruit" value="cherry"/> Cherry<br/>
```

Since they all have the same name, when I check one radio-button the others should become unchecked. But in Sharepoint they don't.

What can I do?

If your answer involves JavaScript that would be OK.

Comment: Please put some more code or explain properly

Comment: What exactly is unclear about the code or the question?

Comment: code is unclear because its working fine please share sharepoint scenario in details

Comment: is it one sharepoint column?

Comment: It is not a column, it is not an app. I simply typed HTML-code and when I run it I can check any combination of and even all the buttons.

Comment: Are you saying that when the HTML above is copy/pasted into a SharePoint page that the radio buttons allow for more than one active selection at a time?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying